LED driver schematic
Working on building a driver for an LED headlight, there is a low beam and a high beam circuit that I need help figuring out either a schematic or a pre-existing driver for.  The low beam side would need 21V @ 230mA and the high beam needs 36v @ 230mA.  I know I need to boost the voltage from 12v up to 21v and 36v respectively and limit the output current. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I know the question will get asked, I can't use the existing driver for the headlight assembly as it is controlled by a can-bus system and I can't bypass the need for the can-bus signal.
--- EDIT: ---
The low beam consists of 7 leds in series.
High beam consists of 12 leds in the same configuration.
Each LED can also be run individually or even in groups not sure exactly why.
---EDIT 2!!---
so my initial bench testing was inadequate.  I was being cautious with the LEDs since they are expensive to replace but I was able to drive the low beam up to (approx) 24v and 2A which would put each LED at like 3.4-3.5v and 2A for about 7W of power. Which if this is the case then I should be able to find an off the shelf driver that bumps the 12v source to 24v and current limits to 2 amps. Same for the High beam side. These values seem far more logical and reasonable for a headlight unit as it would be expected of them to be high power individually and as an array. 40w low and 80w high makes far more sense then 7W and 12w.
Thanks to everyone who was helping, I am pretty confident I can find what I need now, unless someone tells me I am horribly wrong in my thinking. I don't feel there is a need to build my own driver as I have seen drivers and such that fit this new information.
pictured is the high beam portion.


how many LEDs are there? ... how are they connected? ... please edit your post... do not write a comment

Usually, brightness is controlled with a constant voltage and variable current.  Does the high-beam setting have a different number of LEDs from the low-beam setting?  Please post a schematic of the LED section of the circuit.

Edited the post, let me know any additional info and I will do my best to get it asap!  I am still learning how to make circuits and how different components work. I do have a solid foundation but building something like an LED driver is just outside of my abilities to figure out.

An incandescent lamp for a headlight is normally 55 W, so 40 W from an LED unit would probably be way above the legal limit for brightness. Think of how you can replace a 60 W incandescent mains bulb for home lighting with a 10 W LED lamp.
